# Magento 2. Frontend. Ui Component. Disable select field after value is selected

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I'm using a M2 custom Ui Component that extends from  `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select` so I have total control over the Javascript File.

How do I disable the field after a value is selected?

Can this be achieved without using a custom JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be achieved without using a custom JS?

No, you need to extend the `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select` component to add new features to the select (disabling it when the value is selected is a new feature).

> How do I disable the field after a value is selected?

You can do this by subscribing to the `value` property of your custom select, which is "inherited" from the `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select` component, and disable the select in the callback.

To disable the select, you can change the value of the `disabled` property (which is an KnockoutJS observable) to `true`, or simply call the `this.disable()` method.

Here's a basic example:

```js
define([
  'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select'
], function(Select) {

  return Select.extend({
    initialize() {
      this._super();

      this.value.subscribe(() => {
        this.disable();
        // OR
        this.disabled(true);
      });
    }
  });
});
```